# Fully expanded form of the dates (years, specially) and their case aspects

Tags: падежи, числительные

I want to understand the case aspects of the dates in Russian (I think that rather than learning them as a rule of thumb, after understanding them I won't forget them so easily). So far, I only came across two forms of dates: (a) nominative, e.g.

> 03.12.2008: третье декабря две тысячи восьмого года

and (b) after the preposition *в*, for instance

> On Friday 1.04.1962: в пятницу первого апреля тысяча девятьсот шестьдесят второго года

**Attempt of explanation:** The way I understand (a) is as the literal (not correct English) translation of *the third of december of the year two thousand eight*. So *third* stands in nominative, *of december* is *декабря* (in genitive). Moreover, one uses *две* and not *двa* because *тысяча* is feminine; *тысячи* is the genitive form of *thousand* induced by the number 2, and the last genitive *"восьмого года"* comes from the possessive in "*of the year 2008*".

The way I understand (b) is essencially the same, except that the preposition *в* induces accusative(?) on the day of the week, and now the number of day, in this case 1, stands in genitive (why?).

**Questions:**

1. Which errors can you find in this explanation? If so, kindly provide a better understanding.
2. Which case is used for the dates when dealing with periods of time? Is the year modified? For instance "20" and "31" and the years in:

   > С 20 декабря 1999 по 31 декабря 2002
3. Is there something more to know about how to say the dates in Russian?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To begin with, I must point out that in Russian, when we say dates, e.g., `03.12.2008`, the name of the month is an attribute in Genitive to the number of the date (03 in this example), this number of the date itself is an ordinal number in the neuter gender, it agrees with the word `число` (number), which is neuter and is almost always omitted, and the number of the year is an attribute in Genitive to the name of the month:

> 03.12.2008 - Третье [число] декабря две тысячи восьмого года (Word for word: *The 3rd [number] of December of the 2008th year).

Different prepositions used before dates govern different cases, but **the attributes in Genitive (usually the month and the year) *always* remain in Genitive. If the name of the day of the week or a name of a holiday is used before the date, then the number of the day also becomes an attribute in Genitive to these latter.** In other words, only the first word in the date is declined, all the other words are in Genitive.

In English, however you name a day (Friday, Easter, April 1), you use "on": `on Friday, on Easter, on April 1`. In Russian, in every of these cases it will be different:

- `B` + Accusative, if it's the day of the week: `В понедельник, в среду, в пятницу, в воскресенье`;
- `На` + Accusative, if it's the name of a holiday: `На Рождество, на Новый год, на Пасху`;
- No preposition, the number in Genitive, then followed by Genitive of the the name of the month, the year, AD / BC, if you use the numerical date designation: `Первого апреля две тысячи тринадцатого года нашей эры`. The number of the year is an ordinal numeral in Russian, while in English it's cardinal. In longer Russian ordinal numerals of several words only the last numeral pronounced is, actually, ordinal, the first ones are cardinal, and, when declined, it is only this last numeral pronounced that is declined (the declinable numeral is italicized):

> 1000 год - *тысячный* год - Первого апреля *тысячного* года
>
> 1900 год - тысяча *девятисотый* год - Первого апреля тысяча *девятисотого* года
>
> 1901 год - тысяча девятьсот *первый* год - Первого апреля тысяча девятьсот *первого* года
>
> 1915 год - тысяча девятьсот *пятнадцатый* год - Первого апреля тысяча девятьсот *пятнадцатого* года
>
> 1999 год - тысяча девятьсот девяносто *девятый* год - Первого апреля тысяча девятьсот девяносто *девятого* года
>
> 2000 год - *двухтысячный* год - Первого апреля *двухтысячного* года

- If you name periods longer than a day, you use "in" in English (`in April, in 2013, in the 21st century`). In Russian, the pattern is `B` + Prepositional: `В апреле, в две тысячи тринадцатом году, в двадцать первом веке`. If you combine the month and the year (`In April, 2013`), it follows the same pattern, only the number of the year, together with the word `год`,  is in Genitive: `В апреле две тысячи тринадцатого года`.

> С 20 декабря 1999 по 31 декабря 2002

Here the number of the day after `C` is in Genitive, and the number of the day after `По` is in Accusative (in the ordinal numerals of several words, naturally, only the last word in declined):

> С 20 декабря 1999 по 31 декабря 2002 - С двадцатого декабря тысяча девятьсот девяносто девятого года по тридцать первое декабря две тысячи второго года.